# transport stored procedure securely

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on a project that has versions. If a new version is ready to publish, I prepare stored procedures to update the database by the DBA. I sent him the SPs and he executes them. However, I don't want the DBA to see my SP codes. Is it possible transport stored procedure without showing the code to the DBA.

Comment: It seems to me like you are searching for a technical solution for a social problem. And it won't solve the problem. When the DBA doesn't allow you to run stored procedures on the server yourself, he will certainly not run any procedures you wrote which he can not read.

Comment: What stops the DBA from from running `sp_helptext` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx?

Comment: I work for a bank. The DBA has the authentication to execute the SP but I don't. However, I have signed a paper for security responsibility of the application. Therefore,the bank and me have no trust problem. The DBA can change the stored procedure. At least, he can stole my code. I have spent 6 years to develop this software. And I don't wan't him to use my code freely. Why the stuckoverflow users have problem to got the question. If you know a method answer the question. I did not ask for your Ideas about the problem. Is it social or something. BLa bla. Only need to solution. CLEAR?

Comment: The dba is responsible for the production database. If I were him I would have you fired if you tried to obscure the code so he couldn't see it.

Comment: It sounds like you have roles swapped. You should be the DBA.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to provide the SQL Stored Proc in an Encrypted text file.And write your own app in .NET which will read the Encrypted SQL Text ,decrypt it and then deploy to the Selected Server.

If you work in .NET then you will know how easy it is to write such an app.Just provide that App with your stored Procs.DBA will be able to deploy the stored proc using that App wihout seeing them.
For simple scenarios you can hardcode the 'Password' required to decrypt the SQL Text but for more sensitive scenarios you can use PKI.

Like all other solutions, this solution can be reverse engineered but IMHO a better option than re-writing your Stored Proc logic in CLR.

Note:i am assuming you will use `WITH ENCRYPTION` option to create the Stored Proc.

Comment: I wasn't actually aware the the `WITH ENCRYPTION` option, +1

Comment: WITH ENCRYPTION was the best option. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you ship CLR stored procedures and obfuscate the assemblies then the functionality would be relaitvely well hidden.

I would suggest that this would be the **WRONG** motivation for using CLR stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it and let you know the result.

Comment: They could still run SQL Profiler and see what queries are actually executed by the SQL Engine. It would be very difficult to stop someone competent from reverse engineering any functional code but, it would raise the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Phillip already commented, If I was the guy executing your stored procedures I would have a huge issue running stuff on my DB I can not read.

If you want your code unreadable at first glance, try obfuscation (one form or another is nearly always available - if you just use BASE64 encoded/decoded strings with execute immediate)

For everything above that, you would require encrypted stored procedures, but that depends on the system and I don't know tsql enough to tell you.